# Space Complexity - Dropping the non-dominant terms

Tags: space-complexity

I know, we should drop the non-dominant terms when calculating time complexity  of an algorithm. I am wondering if we should drop them when calculating **space complexity**. For example, if I have a string of N letters, I'd like to:

1. construct a list of letters from this string -> Space: O(N);
2. sort this list -> Worst-case space complexity for Timsort (I use Python): O(N).

In this case, would the entire solution take O(N) + O(N) space or just O(N)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!
First of all, I think you do misunderstand complexity: Complexity is defined independently of constant factors. It depends only on the large scale behavior of the data set size `N`. Thus, `O(N) + O(N)` is the same complexity as `O(N)`.
Thus, your question might have been:
If I construct a list of letters using an algorithm with `O(N)` space complexity, followed by a sort algorithm with `O(N)` space complexity, would the entire solution use twice as much space?
But this question cannot be answered, since a complexity does not give you any measure how much space is actually used.
A well-known example: A brute force sorting algorithm, BubbleSort, with time complexity `O(N^2)` is faster for small data sets than a very good sorting algorithm, QuickSort, with average time complexity `O(Nlog(N))`.

**EDIT:**

It is no contradiction, that one can compute a space complexity, and that it does not say how much space is actually used.

A simple example:

Say,  for a certain problem algorithm 1 has linear space complexity `O(n)`, and algorithm 2 space complexity `O(n^2)`.
One could thus assume (but this is wrong) that algorithm 1 would always use less space than algorithm 2.
First, it is clear that for large enough `n` algorithm 2 will use more space than algorithm 1, because `n^2` grows faster than `n`.
However, consider the case where `n` is small enough, say `n = 1`, and algorithm 1 is implemented on a computer that uses storage in doubles (64 bits), whereas algorithm 2 is implemented on a computer that uses bytes (8 bits). Then, obviously, the `O(n^2)` algorithm uses less space than the `O(n)` algorithm.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It's more clear now. I, however, wonder how can I calculate a space complexity of a problem solution on an interview if "a complexity does not give you any measure how much space is actually used".

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so, I suggest to accept it, so that the question is marked as answered. If not, maybe you are more interested in a comparison how much space is used by different algorithms on the same hardware. But this is a different question and has nothing to do with [complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms).